# Написание слова «остров» в составе названий государств

Tags: орфография, топонимика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать слово «остров» в составе названий государств: с прописной или строчной буквы? Дело в том, что нигде не нашла написание «Фолклендские острова» с прописной буквы, хотя правило гласит, что в официальных названиях государств, административных территорий слово Острова пишется с прописной (нашла информацию на «Грамоте.ру»). Написания, например, «Каймановы Острова», «Сейшельские Острова», находила, а с «Фолклендскими островами» не могу разобраться…

Comment: Обратите внимание, что в названии вопроса Вы спрашиваете о государствах. Но Фолкленды — не государство. В данном случае это имеет решающее значение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за быстрый ответ! Да, согласна, что Фолклендские острова -- не государство, а часть британской заморской территории (если я правильно понимаю), но Каймановы острова -- тоже часть британской заморской территории (опять же если не ошибаюсь), поэтому и не могу понять...

Comment: Вот интересный материал по теме https://aif.ru/dontknows/1225965

Comment: Да, тоже попадалась мне эта статья, но спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы. В данном случае Грамота ошиблась дважды — сначала дали неправильный ответ, а потом настаивали на несуществующем государстве.

Надёжнее всего проверять по словарям. Есть орфографический словарь Лопатина "Как правильно? С большой буквы или с маленькой?". Там и по Каймановым и по Фолклендским островам даётся только один вариант написания (острова с маленькой). Но, например, по Маршалловым — два варианта: с большой для государств и с маленькой для островов.

> 1. острова, -ов (группа островов,
>    архипелаг), напр.: Бермудские
>    острова, Канарские острова,
>    Балеарские острова, Маршалловы острова. Сейшельские
>    острова. Коморские острова,
>    острова Зеленого мыса, Соломоновы острова, Большие
>    Зондские острова, Восточно-Фризские острова. Новосибирские острова, Ближние острова (в архипелаге Алеутские
>    острова)
> 2. Острова, -ов (в офиц. названиях
>    государств, административных
>    территории), напр.: Республика Маршалловы Острова, Республика Сейшельские Острова, Федеральная Исламская
>    Республика Коморские Острова, Соломоновы Острова (государства), Балеарские Острова,
>    Канарские Острова (автономные области в Испании)

Поэтому не сомневайтесь: **Фолклендские острова**.

Comment: Очень благодарю вас!! Еще и словарь мне подсказали!) Давно искала ответ, не могла нигде найти... Только все равно интересно, почему некоторые острова только со строчной, а некоторые с прописной...) Буду тогда ссылаться на словарь Лопатина) Спасибо большое еще раз!)

Answer (score 0):

> В названии Каймановы острова слово острова может быть написано с
> маленькой буквы – если речь идет об архипелаге. Но если имеется в виду
> наименование государства, написание острова невозможно, т. к. в
> официальных названиях государств все слова (кроме служебных) пишутся с
> большой буквы.

[ссылка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&start=15)

Comment: Вы привели правило, но забыли ответить на сам вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Фолклендские Острова (Мальвинские) - есть такая страна в соответствии к классификатором "Страны мира".